# Message box is not visible

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have modHolder class object

```
class modHolder : public CWinThread
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(modHolder)

protected:
    modHolder();          
    virtual ~modHolder();

public:
    CMainWindow * v1;
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    virtual int ExitInstance();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

That is created like:

```
AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(modHolder));
```

I have frame with button inside of it:

```
class CMainWindow : public CFrameWnd
{
public:

    CMainWindow ();
        CButton m_wndPushButton;

protected:
    afx_msg LRESULT OnMyMessage1(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg  int OnCreate (LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs)   ;
    afx_msg void OnPaint ();
    afx_msg void OnPushButtonClicked ();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP ()

};
```

Whenn I push button it no visible messages are shown:

```
void CMainWindow::OnPushButtonClicked ()   
{   
    MessageBox (_T ("bbb"),_T ("Error"), B_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK);
    //AfxMessageBox("aaaa");
}
```

But message functions do not returns. Why message is not visible?